# how to paste data using last row concept in VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba, find, paste

i have data in A2 to D2 & in column E i have data (which will by chaining day to day - some day it will be 3000 or 4000 or 5000 so on).

so i have to find last row of E column & paste the data of A2 to D2 till last row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way:

```
Range("A2:D2").Copy Destination:=Range("A3:D" & Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row)
```